# Multiple table type parameters in sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to call a T-SQL (SQL Server 2012) stored procedure with more than one table-valued parameter?

I.e.

```
CREATE Type dbo.P1 AS TABLE 
(
    Id Int NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50) NULL
)

CREATE Type dbo.P2 AS TABLE 
(
    Id Int NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50) NULL
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[D]
(
    @id0 Int,
    @P1 dbo.P1 READONLY,
    @P2 dbo.P2 READONLY
)
AS
...
```

I am getting an error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@P2"

Comment: Yes it is possible, The code you have shown in your question is not causing this error. Show the full definition of the stored procedure.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I have found an error (a typo) in the code. If you post your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stored procedures can accept multiple parameters and user-defined type parameters are not any different from a SQL Server system type parameters in this case.

If you only execute the following code it will allow you to create a procedure without any errors, which explains that SQL Server does allow us to create procedures accepting multiple user defined type parameters.

```
--------------------Test ---------------------------------

CREATE Type dbo.P1 AS TABLE 
(
    Id Int NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50) NULL
)
GO

CREATE Type dbo.P2 AS TABLE 
(
    Id Int NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50) NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[D]
(
    @id0 Int,
    @P1 dbo.P1 READONLY,
    @P2 dbo.P2 READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT 'Debugging';
END
GO
```

The error exists somewhere else in your code where you are trying to use a variable which you havent declared. and since you already have a Variable called `@P2` once you have found that variable use a different name for that variable.